# Line thickness for PDF export QGIS

Tags: qgis, pdf

I am trying to export my map project to vector format (i.e. PDF), but somehow cannot get my line thickness right. While a raster export (i.e. PNG) gives me exactly what I have designed, the PDF always comes out too thick, like it can't display thinner lines. Screenshots are below. Any ideas how to solve this?

PNG:
[image]

PDF:
[image]

Comment: Which version of QGIS are you using? I was unable to reproduce the problem in QGIS 3.6

Comment: using 3.4, so you reckon a qgis update could solve it? Did you try really thin lines? It seems to work fine wit all above 1 mm...

Comment: Might be related to the pdf viewer you are using?

Comment: @ndawson any suggestions for a pdf viewer that works? I'm having the same issue with QGIS 3.14 (set line units in mm, tested using Foxit and Adobe Reader)

Comment: I'm using QGIS 3.16.11 and the problem still persists. If the layout is exported as an image, it follows the set stroke width. The only workaround I can do is to set the opacity lower to compensate for the thick stroke.

Answer (score 3):

To force a specific line width in the output file (pdf in this case), set the line width in mm instead of points:

[image: line width settings]

Layouts will honor this setting and pdf will reflect that.

Answer (score -1):

you must lower the opacity of the item, then the lines will print fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).